# Sharepoint 2010 January 2018 Security Update Broke Workflows

Tags: security, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I'm having some problems with workflows that either move documents/document sets or update their paths. The workflows were performing perfectly until around the time we did the Jan. 2018 security update. The only error message I have to go on is "unknown error." Does anybody know of anything in the update that could have caused this feature to stop performing correctly?

Comment: More details are needed. What have you tried so far?

Comment: We originally thought it was a problem with an impersonation step to preserve some permissions, but after rewriting that part of the workflow the same issues popped up. That's when we found out that a different workflow was unable to update a pathway and place a document in a document set. That part does not use an impersonation step so we ruled out the problem being in the workflows. Does that help? I'm fairly inexperienced in sharepoint, if that's not already obvious.

Comment: U check through uls logs?

Comment: I don’t know what to look for in them.

Comment: You should consider contacting their support.

Comment: They don't offer support anymore.

Comment: In your 14 hives logs, there must be some exceptions related to your workflow also you can check what security update was installed on